# No account access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am an account administrator (not the owner)

I can't access almost anything. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the Administrator account be associated with the meaning of this name and let me do everything?

I would like to change and implement Cloud Function but I don't have permission

A message is displayed that I do not have permission and I should execute this code:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding projectID --member=user: --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

But this also requires some authority

Comment: What IAM roles do you actually have for your account? Administrator is not a Google Cloud IAM role.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't even have permission to `iam.roles.list`. Can I get this permission myself or who has to do it? That I'm an administrator doesn't give me any permissions?

Comment: You are not an administrator. You will need to ask the account Owner to grant you required permissions.

Comment: @JohnHanley There is a role in the permissions tab next to my email  `Administrator Firebase`. Does this mean that I have administrator rights?

Comment: The role `roles/firebase.admin` only has access to Firebase services. Refer to this document on the permissions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-all-products

Comment: Do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The role `roles/firebase.admin` only has access to the Firebase services. Refer to this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-all-products) on the permissions.

You'll need to ask the account Owner to grant you required permissions.